# i don't know how to fix this Performing Mail merge

Tags: c#

I'm from Vietnam.

[link demo](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/docio/getting-started)

This is my code in word but it doesn't work

```
«TableStart:ListChiTieu»
«STT»
«TenChiTieu»
«DonViTinh»
«MucCongBo»
«TableEnd:ListChiTieu»
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set mail merge fields correctly in word document before do anything.

It doesnt work if you only type `<<STT>>`. It should be a mail merge field. Then only syncfusion can identify that as mail merge field and do the data binding.

[Insert mail merge fields](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-mail-merge-fields-9a1ab5e3-2d7a-420d-8d7e-7cc26f26acff)

Then follow example in [syncfusion](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/docio/getting-started?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#performing-mail-merge) until you get correct results.